# Dynamically Creating Lightning:inputField components for a form based on a list of field names

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am basically trying to dynamically create a range of lightning:inputFields to be populated as part of a lightning:recordEditForm. I seem to be able to use the code to create random buttons etc based on the fields in my list of fields, however the functionality should allow me to dynamically generate a form for edit etc. Please take a look at sample code:

```
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

    <aura:attribute name="showSpinner" type="Boolean" default="false" />
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="selectedRecordTypeId" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="recordFormSubmitted" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="showOpportunityEdit" type="Boolean" default="true"/>
    <aura:attribute name="showOpportunitySummary" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="opportunityFields" type="String[]" default="[OwnerId, Name, IsPrivate, CloseDate, StageName]"/>

    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showSpinner}">
        <lightning:spinner />
    </aura:if>

    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showOpportunityEdit}">
        <lightning:recordEditForm
                aura:id="opportunityEditForm"
                recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                onload="{!c.handleLoad}"
                onsubmit="{!c.handleSubmit}"
                onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}"
                recordTypeId="{!v.selectedRecordTypeId}"
                objectApiName="Opportunity">
            <!-- the messages component is for error messages -->
            <lightning:messages />
            <lightning:layout>
                <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" size="3"/>

                <lightning:layoutItem flexibility="auto" padding="around-small" size="6">
                    <lightning:layout multipleRows="true">
                        <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" flexibility="auto">
                            {!v.body}
                            <!--{!v.opportunityEditFormLHS}-->
                            <!--<lightning:inputField fieldName="OwnerId" />-->
                            <!--<lightning:inputField fieldName="Name" />-->
                            <!--<lightning:inputField fieldName="IsPrivate" />-->
                        </lightning:layoutItem>
                        <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" flexibility="auto">
                            <!--{!v.opportunityEditFormRHS}-->
                            <!--<lightning:inputField fieldName="CloseDate" />-->
                            <!--<lightning:inputField fieldName="StageName" />-->
                        </lightning:layoutItem>
                    </lightning:layout>
                </lightning:layoutItem>

                <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" size="3"/>

            </lightning:layout>
        </lightning:recordEditForm>
    </aura:if>
```

As you can see Im using the {v.body} tag where I want the lightning:inputs to be visible.

This is my init method:

```
doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
    for (var i = 0; i < component.get("v.opportunityFields").length; i ++) {
        console.log(component.get("v.opportunityFields")[i]);
        $A.createComponent(
            "lightning:inputField",
            {
                "fieldName": component.get("v.opportunityFields")[i]
            },
            function(newInputField, status, errorMessage){
                //Add the new button to the body array
                if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                    var body = component.get("v.body");
                    body.push(newInputField);
                    component.set("v.body", body);
                }
                else if (status === "INCOMPLETE") {
                    console.log("No response from server or client is offline.")
                    // Show offline error
                }
                else if (status === "ERROR") {
                    console.log("Error: " + errorMessage);
                    // Show error message
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out, I was initializing my String[] array with Values excluding 'value', which resulted in nothing being created. This is the complete code working:

```
doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
        for (var i = 0; i < component.get("v.opportunityFields").length; i ++) {
            console.log(component.get("v.opportunityFields")[i]);
            $A.createComponent(
                "lightning:inputField",
                {
                    "fieldName": component.get("v.opportunityFields")[i]
                },
                function(newInputField, status, errorMessage){
                    //Add the new button to the body array
                    if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                        var body = component.get("v.body");
                        body.push(newInputField);
                        component.set("v.body", body);
                    }
                    else if (status === "INCOMPLETE") {
                        console.log("No response from server or client is offline.")
                        // Show offline error
                    }
                    else if (status === "ERROR") {
                        console.log("Error: " + errorMessage);
                        // Show error message
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    }
```

As for the String[] declaration that has been fixed:

```
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

    <aura:attribute name="showSpinner" type="Boolean" default="false" />
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="selectedRecordTypeId" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="recordFormSubmitted" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="showOpportunityEdit" type="Boolean" default="true"/>
    <aura:attribute name="showOpportunitySummary" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="opportunityFields" type="String[]" default="['OwnerId', 'Name', 'IsPrivate', 'CloseDate', 'StageName']"/>

    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showSpinner}">
        <lightning:spinner />
    </aura:if>

    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showOpportunityEdit}">
        <lightning:recordEditForm
                aura:id="opportunityEditForm"
                recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                onload="{!c.handleLoad}"
                onsubmit="{!c.handleSubmit}"
                onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}"
                recordTypeId="{!v.selectedRecordTypeId}"
                objectApiName="Opportunity">
            <!-- the messages component is for error messages -->
            <lightning:messages />
            <lightning:layout>
                <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" size="3"/>

                <lightning:layoutItem flexibility="auto" padding="around-small" size="6">
                    <lightning:layout multipleRows="true">
                        <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" flexibility="auto">
                            {!v.body}
                            <!--{!v.opportunityEditFormLHS}-->
                            <!--<lightning:inputField fieldName="OwnerId" />-->
                            <!--<lightning:inputField fieldName="Name" />-->
                            <!--<lightning:inputField fieldName="IsPrivate" />-->
                        </lightning:layoutItem>
                        <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" flexibility="auto">
                            <!--{!v.opportunityEditFormRHS}-->
                            <!--<lightning:inputField fieldName="CloseDate" />-->
                            <!--<lightning:inputField fieldName="StageName" />-->
                        </lightning:layoutItem>
                    </lightning:layout>
                </lightning:layoutItem>

                <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" size="3"/>

            </lightning:layout>
        </lightning:recordEditForm>
    </aura:if>
```